# Android - Issue with conversion of double to Big Decimal

Tags: java, android

I am trying to convert the user's input from the `EditText` into a `Big Decimal`. However, I am having problems doing that. My result is not converted. For example, after the computation is done, the number will be 12.345678. After calling method `round()`, the rounded value is still the same. Am I doing something wrong? I'm dealing with money

.java

```
            double totalPrice = Double.parseDouble(price.getText().toString());

            int position = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
            name = name1.getText().toString();

            if(position == 0)
            {
                totalPrice = totalPrice * 1.07;
                System.out.println(totalPrice);
            }
            else
            {
                totalPrice = (totalPrice * 1.1)*1.07;
                System.out.println(totalPrice);
            }

            round(totalPrice, 2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);

            }

}

public static double round(double unrounded, int precision, int roundingMode)
{
    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(unrounded);
    BigDecimal rounded = bd.setScale(precision, roundingMode);
    return rounded.doubleValue();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not *using* the result of `round`. You should *at least* be doing:

```
totalPrice = round(totalPrice, 2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
```

However, you shouldn't be using `double` for currency values to start with. Use `BigDecimal` throughout - otherwise you may well find you get unexpected results due to the way binary floating point works.

Comment: Specifically, avoid using `Double.parseDouble`, and use `new BigDecimal(String)` from the get-go.

Comment: Jon - Thanks, now it works. I thought `totalPrice` would be automatically initialized with the new value.

Louis - Thanks for the info. Have changed it to using BigDecimal instead of double. Although using BigDecimal was a little more hassle using BigDecimal than doubles having the need to declare new BigDecimal multiplicands. But at least it would avoid problems like what Jon pointed out.